# How to display error messages via function php

Tags: php

The goal is to have the results of a foreach loop display an array's content in the form page. I'm have been able to display error messages, but not more than one when several exist. Currently the code returns collection array with many lines but my purpose is to generate line by line via respective condition.

index.php

```
<tbody>
            <?php
include './function/check.php';
            foreach ($urls as $url) {
                ?>


                <tr>
                    <td><a href="detail.php"> <?php print_r($url[2]); ?></a></td>
                    <td><a href="detail.php?pno=<?php print_r($url[1]); ?>"><?php print_r($url[1]); ?></a></td>


                    <td> 
                        <?php

                            var_dump($output);

                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>

    </tbody>
```

check.php

```
<?php


  include 'checkfunction.php';


  if (isset($_POST['sourceDir'])) {
  $sourceDir = $_POST['sourceDir'];
  $urls = array();
  $linecount = 1;
  $output = array();
  $errmsg = '';
  if (is_dir($sourceDir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($sourceDir)) {
        while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {

            if ($filename != "." && $filename != ".." && strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1)) == 'php') {
                $absolute_path = str_replace('\\', '/', $sourceDir) . '/';
                $readfile = fopen($absolute_path . $filename, 'r');

                if ($readfile) {
                    while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets($readfile))) {
                        $ary = check($line, $linecount, $filename);
                        if ($ary != null) {
                            array_push($urls, $ary);

                            $errmsg = array($errmsg);
                            $out1 = '';
                            foreach ($errmsg as $k => $v) {
                                $out1 = $v;
                                $output[] = $out1;
                            }


                            var_dump($output);


                        }
                        $linecount++;
                    }
                    fclose($readfile);
                }
                $linecount = 1;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
}
?>
```

checkfunction.php

```
<?php

function check($line, $linecount, $filename) {
global $errmsg;

$urls = array($line, $linecount, $filename);
if (preg_match("/\=/", $line)) {
    if (preg_match("/\\s\=\\s/i", $line) || preg_match("/\\s\==\\s/", $line) || preg_match("/\\s\===\\s/", $line)) {

    } else {
        $errmsg = "There should be space before and after of equal";

        return $urls;
    }
} elseif (strpos($line, 'if') !== false) {
    if (preg_match("/\!\\\$[a-zA-z0-9]/i", $line)) {
        $errmsg = "•If you want to use ifcondition, don't use !.Use false === ";
        return $urls;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why are there two } } (curly brackets) in the code?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I want to show errmsg from checkfunction.php to index.php

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ini_set('display_errors',1);` after the  opening in the first page.

It's the equivalent to enabling error_reporting in php.ini

//I hope thats, what you're looking for..

Comment: I am sorry,I am looking for the error messages from checkfunction.php to display in index.php

Answer (score 0):

to do that you need to use a foreach loop, try this :

```
$errors = array(); //consider this is the array where ur storing all the errors, im doing this to make it more logical  
//for each item in the array store it in a new variable named $error, and then we echo it :
foreach($errors as $error){
      //you can also style all the errors, or make them a part of a <ul> like this
      echo '<ul>
            <li>'.$error.'</li>
            </ul>';
}
```

this should display all the error messages you have

Comment: its work but I would like to show error messages in index.php page not in check.php.

Comment: then you have to include check.php in index.php and call the function in checkfunction.php

Comment: I did it but all of the error messages are ok to echo in check.php.But it's not work when I called in index.php

Comment: where did you call it, can you upload somewhere ?

Comment: I called your code in check.php..Its work and show all messages what I want.but I want to show in index.php page that's why I foreach loop in index.php page but it's not work and only show last line from loop

Comment: can you please edit the question and add my code to check.php, i would like to see where you put it